# ChromeDriver selenium java Raspberry pi

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, raspberry-pi3

I'm creating a crawler that needs to open a browser to connect a website. I'm windows it is actually working with ChromeDriver but I can't do it work in Raspbian.

First I installed the ChromeDirver from here:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=armhf&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=chromedriver

using the armhf package and It installed correctly, but when I try to open my program, when it starts to load the driver, fails, with the next error:

/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libbase.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I saw inside Chromium lib directory and there is not this library. I'm using a raspberry pi 3. How to install it?

Answer (score -1):

Do the following

`sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/chrome_lib.conf`

Then paste the following

`/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libs`

then press `ctrl+o`. Press `Enter`. Then press `ctrl+x`

Then run `$sudo ldconfig`

Then try again

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did, but in this directory, there is not this library.